# Getting wrong dimension image after cutting image from center

Tags: c#, .net, image

I am trying to crop image from center and want to generate image with `100 * 46` dimensions but i am getting image with `46 * 17` dimension.

**Code:**

```
 SaveCroppedImage(Image.FromStream(file.InputStream), 100, 46, "MyfilePath", true);

public void SaveCroppedImage(Image image, UInt16 thumbWidth, UInt16 thumbHeight, string filePath, Boolean checkDimension)
        {
            if (checkDimension && image.Width > image.Height)
            {
                var tmp = thumbHeight;
                thumbHeight = thumbWidth;
                thumbWidth = tmp;
            }

            if (image.Width > thumbWidth || image.Height > thumbHeight)
            {
                float scaleWidth = 1;
                float scaleHeight = 1;
                float scale = 1;
                scaleWidth = ((float)thumbWidth / (float)image.Width);
                scaleHeight = ((float)thumbHeight / (float)image.Height);

                if (scaleWidth < scaleHeight)
                {
                    scale = scaleWidth;
                }
                else
                {
                    scale = scaleHeight;
                }
                thumbWidth = (UInt16)Math.Round(image.Width * scale, 0);
                thumbHeight = (UInt16)Math.Round(image.Height * scale, 0);

            }

            if (thumbWidth > image.Width)
                thumbWidth = (UInt16)image.Width;

            if (thumbHeight > image.Height)
                thumbHeight = (UInt16)image.Height;

            //System.Drawing.Image thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(thumbWidth, thumbHeight, new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), IntPtr.Zero);
            System.Drawing.Image thumb = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
            System.Drawing.Graphics gr = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(thumb);

            gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gr.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.High;

            System.Drawing.Rectangle rectDestination = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
            gr.DrawImage(image, rectDestination, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            //
            // get raw format
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format = image.RawFormat;

            //
            // get encoder
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo info = null;
            foreach (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo ici in System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
            {
                if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg.Equals(format))
                {
                    info = ici;
                    break;
                }
                else if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif.Equals(format))
                {
                    info = ici;
                    break;
                }
                else if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png.Equals(format))
                {
                    info = ici;
                    break;
                }
                else if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp.Equals(format))
                {
                    info = ici;
                    break;
                }
                else if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff.Equals(format))
                {
                    info = ici;
                    break;
                }
                else if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Wmf.Equals(format))
                {
                    info = ici;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // check if we found the right encoder, otherwise use the rawformat and save
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                if (info == null)
                {
                    thumb.Save(stream, format);
                }
                else
                {
                    //
                    // create parameters and save
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters encParams = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1);
                    encParams.Param[0] = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
                    thumb.Save(stream, info, encParams);
                }

                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                StoreFile(stream, filePath);
                image.Dispose();
            }
            gr.Dispose();
        }

private static Boolean StoreFile(Stream fileStream, String filePath, Boolean overwriteIfExists = true)
        {
            if (fileStream.CanSeek) fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var fileWasWritten = false;
            try
            {
                using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    if (stream.CanSeek) stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    fileStream.CopyTo(stream);
                }

                fileWasWritten = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

            return fileWasWritten;
        }
```

My sample input image:[Trial Image](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=download%20images%20of%20animals&biw=1600&bih=789&tbm=isch&imgil=Fnj7w0oEGsm8dM%253A%253BM_qkXIYDWn5K2M%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fbeautifuldesktopwallpaper.blogspot.com%25252F2012%25252F01%25252Fwild-animal-gallery-wild-animal-photo.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=Fnj7w0oEGsm8dM%253A%252CM_qkXIYDWn5K2M%252C_&usg=__Srq4Iz56DoldvqBxcvYRFcvyLBI%3D#imgrc=Fnj7w0oEGsm8dM%3A)

**Output Image**:
[image]

I am trying to save image that format only which user image has.For Eg:If user selected image is in png format then i would like to save image in
png format only and if image is in jpg format then save image in jpg format.

I have tried code from below link  but code from below link produces very bad quality image:

[Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/683699/Cropping-an-Image-from-Center-i)

Comment: I can't see it in the code, but could you be mixing up width and height somewhere in your calls? You want 100x **46** but get **46** x17

Comment: Look into the Dpi of the image! If it is different from your screen dpi ypu will get wrong resluts!

Answer (score 1):

As the Image width is always bigger than the height this condition always is true

```
if (checkDimension && image.Width > image.Height)
```

and switches the dimensions of your result image.

If you wanted this to check for the image oriantation you could do something like:

```
 var oriantationthumb = (thumbWidth/(float)thumbHeight) > 1;
 var oriantationImage = (imageWidth/(float)imageHeight) > 1;

 if(oriantationthumb != oriantationImage)
 {
  //exchange 
 }
```

Comment: So in order to fix this can you recommend any solution please

Comment: Commenting out that top if condition if (checkDimension && image.Width > image.Height) still produces image with dimension 100 * 38  instead of 100 * 46

Comment: the code preserves the original images aspect ration. So if the original does not happen to be the same as 100 to 46 it will match to fit

Comment: Still dimension is 100 * 38 instead of 100 * 46

Comment: The code you are using ins written to keep the aspect ratio. If you don't want this you have to remove the `scale` variable and use scalewidth/scaleHeight respectively. You will get the output you want, but the image will be skewed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125899/discussion-between-learning-and-dawnkeeper).